# Unordered insert into Mongodb using mongolite

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

The following example performs an unordered insert of three documents. With unordered inserts, if an error occurs during an insert of one of the documents, MongoDB continues to insert the remaining documents in the array:

```
db.products.insert(
[
{ _id: 20, item: "lamp", qty: 50, type: "desk" },
{ _id: 21, item: "lamp", qty: 20, type: "floor" },
{ _id: 22, item: "bulk", qty: 100 }
],
{ ordered: false }
)
```

Is this possible with mongolite? I am using a dataframe to insert data into mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mongo` shell converts multiple insert statements into a [bulk insert operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#ordered-and-unordered-bulk-operations), which is where the ordered vs unordered behaviour applies. The Bulk API was introduced in MongoDB 2.6; older versions of MongoDB had a batch insert API which had an option to "continue on error" that defaulted to `false`.

The `mongolite` R package builds on the officially supported `libmongoc` driver, but as at `mongolite 1.2` does not properly expose an option to control the behaviour of bulk inserts. However, the underlying  `mongolite` C functions do have a `stop_on_error` boolean (default: `TRUE`) which maps to ordered vs unordered inserts.

I've submitted a pull request ([mongolite #99](https://github.com/jeroen/mongolite/pull/99)) which will pass through the `stop_on_error` parameter for bulk inserts.

This doesn't change the default `mongolite` behaviour, which will be to stop at the first error encountered in a bulk insert. With `stop_on_error` set to `FALSE`, errors will be summarised for each batch of bulk inserts.

Sample usage (where `data` could be any valid parameter for `insert()` such as a data frame, named list, or character vector with JSON strings):

```
coll$insert(data, stop_on_error = FALSE)
```

It may make more sense to rename the parameter from `stop_on_error` to `ordered` for consistency with the bulk API, but I'll leave that to the discretion of the `mongolite` maintainer.

Comment: I did saw your pull request and it is what I need. I don't know how to make your pull request available for use. Should I wait for the maintainers to merge it?

Comment: When I try to use  devtools::install_github("stennie/mongolite/tree/issue-98") it gives me Installation failed: Does not appear to be an R package (no DESCRIPTION)

Comment: I used `devtools::install_github("stennie/mongolite", branch="issue-98")` and it worked but the downloaded vesrion was the 1.2

Comment: I used `devtools::install_github("stennie/mongolite", ref="issue-98")` and it worked! thanks man!